# contactform.php messing up site

Tags: templating, config, php, plugin-contactform, configuration

I've tried creating a `contactform.php` file with the [P&T Contact Form plugin](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm) and using the code in the documentation to be able to programmatically add recipients. However, when I use this code:

```
<?php
    namespace Craft;

    $toEmail = craft()->request->getPost('toEmail');
    $toEmail = craft()->security->validateData($toEmail);

    return array(
        'toEmail' => ($toEmail ?: null),
        ...
    );
```

I end up getting a white screen of death and a 500 Internal Server Error. I don't know why it's doing this, I tried editing the permissions of my `craft` folder and the `contactform.php` file, but nothing has worked and I keep getting a white screen.

How can I fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: If you enable [devMode](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#devMode), instead of a white screen, you should get a nice error message with a stack trace. If you don't, can you edit the original question to include your `contactform.php` file?

Comment: I used the code that I included above and I did also try devMode, but I couldn't get any errors. Where should I go from here? Would there be any problems related to the comma and ellipsis in the array? It was originally included in the source code in the documentation... either way, are there any other things I can try?

Comment: Yeah, if you don't get any errors with devMode enabled, then it's probably a PHP syntax error in your `contactform.php` file, which is why I asked if you could edit your original question with the contents of that file. ;)

Comment: Thanks. Like I said though, what I included above is the complete contents of the `contactform.php`. :) is that not what you need?

Comment: lol, no that's it. I'm just dense. Will add an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `...` in your `contactform.php` file.

The docs use it because they assume you might have some other valid config settings you want to include in that config file, but it's not real code, which is why PHP is choking on it.

Remove the `...` and you should be set.